# How to give specific value to mesh in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to give specific value(not a position or color) to each triangles. I tried to find this, but i could find how to change vertex's position or add vertex in mesh. How to find this?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "give specific value"? Just giving value coresponding to each triangle?

Comment: do you mean is "UV" information ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawProcedural.html

Comment: @MyBug18 yes, that is what i want.

Comment: @TimChang  i know uv is about position value for shader, but i want to give only specific value to triangles.

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude i think it's function for drawing, if that, it;s not i think

Comment: It definitely is, I misunderstand your question then. Is it possible to specify exactly what data you are looking for? The answer below is correct if you just need the triangles themselves.

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude i will use float data to simulation visualization. i think the answer is befitting. thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the triangles list via

```cs
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
int[] triangles = mesh.triangles
```

The length of the array must be always multiple of 3, because every three consecutive indexes are the indexes of a triangle, from `mesh.vertices` array.

So you can just define an another array, which stores value for your desired behaviour, like:

```cs
private int[] values;

private void Start()
{
    values = new int[triangles.Length / 3];
}
```

And if you index the `values` by `n`, then the corespoinding triangle will be constructed by `triangles[3n]`,`triangles[3n + 1]`,`triangles[3n + 2]`.